# new Thread(runnable, name) return null

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem with a multi-threaded application, bound to button stop thread

```
thread = NULL;
```

after that I start another thread (using the same variable)

```
thread = new Thread(this, "game");
thread.start();
```

after new Thread, thread is still null and I don't know why please help.

Comment: The field `thread` is definitely not `null`.

Comment: Thread finishes too quick.

Comment: It is not possible for a constructor to return null.

Comment: we are going to need more code to debug this one

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik wrong. even if the thread finishes, it does not set it's own reference to null.

Comment: Post more code. It may be that a field is being hidden by a local declared variable of the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information the following is really only speculation.  Please in the future show more details and explain what you have done to debug the problem.

> after new Thread, thread is still null and i don't know why please help.

It is not possible for a constructor to return a `null` so something else is going on.

```
Thread thread = null;
thread = new Thread(this, "game");
// thread is guaranteed to be non-null here
```

Maybe you are sharing the thread field between two threads? For example, maybe your main thread starts the background thread and the UI thread is trying to read it? In that case you should make thread to be `volatile` to be shared between threads.

```
volatile Thread thread = null;
```

If it is already volatile then you you are dealing with a different instance of the `thread` field.  Maybe the `thread` field should be marked as `static`?

Comment: Given the OP's lack of knowledge, i strongly suspect he's using a local variable and not a field. Calling a different method of course has no access to that ``thread`` variable.

Comment: i have access to this field. sometimes this work

Comment: it is static
I have class Game, and there is a static volatile Thread thread
I inheritance from Game and in one thread i stop it and start another thread

Comment: Maybe the thread has not started before the other thread tries to stop it @Dragonow?

Comment: You're right i create new Thread and in other place i set thread=null;